# Using NServiceBus with Azure Service Fabric

Tags: nservicebus, azure-service-fabric

I've read other questions on StackOverflow regarding using NSB on SF and also the sample on github (outdated) and I'm still not sure how to configure NServiceBus properly for this platform.

I'm looking to set up a send only publish/subscribe workflow. What I can't determine through my research is how to set this up so that only one instance of a particular service responds to the message.

For example: 3 services running on the standard 5 nodes (so pretend 5 instances of each of the 3 services).

1. Existing load balancer routes an http request to a specific instance of Service A.
2. Service A publishes the "OrderComplete" event
3. Services B and C both subscribe to the event.
4. How can I make sure that only one instance of Services B and C respond instead of all 5 instances of Service B and all 5 instances of Service C?

All the services are currently Stateless services.

I was thinking of using the AzureServiceBus or AzureStorageQueue transport.

Comment: Did you ever get this answered in some way?

Comment: @CrusherJoe I believe the main piece to it is to use Topics. Create a Topic subscription for Service A and then the first thing to handle the event from that subscription wins, all instances don't get a chance to handle the message unless you created separate subscriptions. So in summary, multiple subscriptions enable multiple things to handle a single message (Topic). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions As the answer states below, all instances of a service will act as competing consumers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stateless approach is fine. You do not need to go into stateful services with a single partition unless you want to leverage reliable collections for your services. But let's look at both options

**Going with Stateless services**

It's ok to have multiple instances of your services. Yes, they all will create subscriptions. I'd argue that is exactly what you want - [competing consumers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568101.aspx). More service instances you have, more throughput you'll get, i.e. handling more messages.

> What I can't determine through my research is how to set this up so that only one instance of a particular service responds to the message.

This will happen automatically due to the nature of the competing consumer transport (both [ASB](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/) and [ASQ](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-storage-queues/)).

**Going with Stateful services**

With stateful services you need to be very careful. Yes, you could go with a single partition per service, hence having a single primary replica handling your messages. But then, arguably, you're wasting your cluster resources by not utilizing them for concurrent processing of many messages. If you decide to partition your service, then you won't be able to use reliable collections as replicas of services **do not** share reliable collections among themselves. Should you choose to use partitioned stateful services w/o reliable collections, well, then you better to utilize stateless counterpart.

**Note**: NSB will provide support for running with stateful services to take advantage of the reliable collections for persistence needs, but even then partitioning is something that would need to be through through to align with business needs. If you do not have a need like that, I'd suggest to stick to stateless services and [Azure Storage persistence](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-storage-persistence/).

Comment: NServiceBus SF persistence repo: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Persistence.ServiceFabric

Answer (score 0):

In the NSB/SF sample on github there is a Stateful service that handles a command. What is important is that in the application it has an `PartitionCount=1`. The same goes for all other solutions with NSB I have seen, only one partition or instance of each service that handles messages. Otherwise you would end up with one subscription per instance for each message as you describe.

Perhaps you could adopt the Distributor to achieve load balancing between multiple instances of the same service, but afaik Distributor only works with MSMQ so you will have to rewrite it to work with SF and Azure Service Bus.

If you stick with single instances, it should work fine for you. You would still get some benefit from SF as it ensures your services are up and running, but load balancing between multiple instances will require some work for you.